# FlatList not rendering with array of arrays of Firestore Snapshots

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I'm just trying to render my Flalist with my state (ListOfProducts), which is an array of arrays of FirestoreDocumentSnapshot that looks like this:

[image: ListOfProducts]

But nothing is rendering. That's my code:

```
return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(listOfProducts)}>
        <Text>Log ListOfProducts</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          style={{flex: 1, width: 200, height: 200}}
          data={listOfProducts}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            item[index].id;
          }}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <Text style={{height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                MON CHIBROS
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Getting my data from Firestore like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = getUserLocation()
      .then((location) => getProducts(location.coords))
      .catch((e) => {
        throw new Error(e.message);
      });

    const getProducts = async (coords) => {
      console.log('getProducts');
      let nearbyGeocollections = await geocollection
        .limit(10)
        .near({
          center: new firestore.GeoPoint(coords.latitude, coords.longitude),
          radius: 50,
        })
        .get();
      let nearbyUsers = [];

      await nearbyGeocollections.forEach((geo) => {
        if (geo.id !== user.uid) {
          firestore()
            .collection('PRODUCTS')
            .doc(geo.id)
            .collection('USER_PRODUCTS')
            .onSnapshot((product) => {
              nearbyUsers.push(product.docs);
            });
        }
      });
      setLoading(false);
      setListOfProducts(nearbyUsers);
    };

    return () => {
      unsubscribe;
      setListOfProducts([]);
    };
  }, []);
```

If someone can point me out what are my mistakes, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: how are you getting data, maybe you forget to call .data().
Please also mention the way you are getting data to get an answer.

Comment: I'm getting data from firestore. I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I got my DocumentSnapshot well, and that's what I wanted.
In your answer I get the data from each DocumentSnapshot. I just gave an answer, I had to rebuild a new object and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the proper way to get data. Try this way

```
firestore()
    .collection('PRODUCTS')
    .doc(geo.id)
    .collection('USER_PRODUCTS')
    .onSnapshot((onResult, onError));

function onResult(QuerySnapshot) {
    var nearbyUsers = [];
    QuerySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        nearbyUsers.push(doc.data());
    });

}

function onError(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

in query snapshot there may be  multiple docs then when you execute doc.data() on each of the doc to get the data from them

Answer (score 0):

I had to rebuild an array of objects to make it works.

```
unsubscribe = await nearbyGeocollections.forEach((geo) => {
  if (geo.id !== user.uid) {
    firestore()
      .collection("PRODUCTS")
      .doc(geo.id)
      .collection("USER_PRODUCTS")
      .onSnapshot((product) => {
        nearbyUsers.push({
          id: product.docs[0].id.toString(),
          products: product.docs,
        });
      });
  }
});
```

My Flatlist:

```
return (
  <>
    <Animated.FlatList
      pagingEnabled={true}
      legacyImplementation={false}
      data={listOfProducts}
      onScroll={onScroll}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: containerPaddingTop }}
      scrollIndicatorInsets={{ top: scrollIndicatorInsetTop }}
      initialNumToRender={5}
      renderItem={(products) => (
        <UserProductsList
          user={user}
          products={products}
          navigation={navigation}
        />
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  </>
);
```